# Save output table from LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I want to left join two tables, but I cannot save the resulting table.

When I use the following code, I get the desired result:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b ON a.ID = b.ID AND a.Name = b.Name
```

However, when I want to save the result in a new table and use:

```
SELECT *
INTO new_table
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b ON a.ID = b.ID AND a.Name = b.Name
```

I get the following error

> Column names in each table must be unique

Based on other questions, I tried addressing this issue the following way:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Name
INTO new_table
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b ON a.ID = b.ID AND a.Name = b.Name
```

However, now the resulting table only contains columns ID and Name. And none of the columns from tableB.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Column names in a table must be unique, you should be selecting each column by its name, using `select *` will not automatically handle any name clashes for you - be specific.

Comment: @Elias for any column common to both tables simply provide an appropriate alias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could alias the columns from A (you really only -need- to alias the columns that need to be unique, but you can optionally assign aliases to the rest) or B using the AS keyword to make them unique and then add all the columns from B

```
SELECT a.ID AS A_ID,
       a.Name AS A_Name,
       b.*
INTO new_table
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b ON a.ID = b.ID and a.Name = b.Name
```